# Can I get sms from pebble sms notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, sms, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I Want to make some apps for Pebble related sms.

When iOS get sms, Pebble notifies sms for me.
My Question is following:

1. Can I get sms content from pebble notification?
2. if above question is not valid, how to get sms content like pebble notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently Pebble apps don't have access to the notifications that stream from your iOS device to your Pebble.

I'm not sure how an iOS app could obtain the notification content, but you can read [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html) to better understand how the Pebble does it.